# Синонимизировать [floating-point], [числа-с-плавающей-точкой] и [float]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать следующие метки (разумеется, в пользу float):

-[floating-point](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point)(26 вопросов, нет описания)

-[числа-с-плавающей-точкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)(60 вопросов, есть описание)

-[float](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/float)(268 вопросов, есть описание)

Причина: "плавающая точка", "числа с плавающей точкой" и "число с плавающей точкой", по сути, являются одинаковыми темами.

Comment: Кажется [css] + [float] это несколько другое.

Comment: Мне кажется логичней будет синонимизировать [floating-point] с [числа-с-плавающей-точкой]

Comment: Это тоже, но основной темы это не отменяет.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 2):

- [floating-point](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) и [числа-с-плавающей-точкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9) - это синонимы.
- [float](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/float) - это конкретный тип данных! И большинство вопросов с этой меткой как раз про тип данных float, а не просто про числа с плавающей точкой. 
   Метке float нужно другое описание, которое будет соответствовать её применению. Описание будет похоже на описание метки [double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double).

Comment: @Kromster пожалуйста, не дописывайте в ответ то, чего его автор не говорил.  Ответ же не общий. Напишите свой ответ, напишите комментарий к ответу.

Comment: На ENSO float был сожжен как раз из-за той проблемы, о которой пишет Kromster: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215292/370389

Comment: Как пожелаете, но тогда и плюс забираю - ответ не раскрывает важную подробность, а автор активно не желает её включать )

Comment: @Kromster "это вообще о другом" - а о чём?

Comment: @Зонтик вы можете легко поискать, что такое "css-float" - The CSS float property specifies how an element should float